# How to make a dll c with make and Makefile

Tags: c, dll, makefile, nmake

I want to compile a c dll in Windows. The Makefile content is:

```
.PHONY: all test mex doc clean

all: 
    cd src && make

test: 
    cd tests && make

mex:
    cd mex && make

doc:
    cd doc && make

clean:
    -rm *~
    cd src && make clean
    cd tests && make clean
    cd mex && make clean
    cd doc && make clean
```

I have installed make from GNU. I open a Visual Studio CMD and run the command:

**nmake Makefile**
and then
**nmake**
and I get this error:
mkdir -p ../obj
The sintax of the command is incorrect
make: *** [../obj/libsegy.o] Error 1
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : código devuelto '0x2'
Stop.

The dll file can be downloaded from: https://www.cs.unm.edu/~negaunt/code/libsegy-1.01.tar.gz

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This makefile is written to run on a POSIX system, most likely GNU/Linux.  You are trying to run it on Windows using native Windows environment.  That can't work, they are not compatible.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much